# tcl error reading package index file

Tags: tcl

I am getting the following error while trying to run a test in automation.

```
 error reading package index file /usr/share/tcl8.4/stc2.0 
/pkgIndex.tcl:      
bad option "join/users/ask/Spirent_TestCenter_4.57
/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux": 
must be atime, attributes, channels, copy, delete, dirname, executable,   
exists, extension, isdirectory, isfile, join, link, lstat, mtime, mkdir,  
nativename, normalize, owned, pathtype, readable, readlink, rename,   
rootname, separator, size, split, stat, system, tail, type, volumes, or 
writable
```

I had to downgrade the Spirent TestCenter application from 4.61 to 4.57 and I changed the package index file accordingly. When it was 4.61, this error was absent.

Comment: Looks like a package specific thing. You might want to ask this on Spirent networks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that a space is missing in a critical location in the file `/users/ask/Spirent_TestCenter_4.57/Spirent_TestCenter_Application_Linux/pkgIndex.tcl`. Guessing what is in that file is a little hard, but it's probably like:

```
package ifneeded stc 4.57 [list source [file join$dir something...]]
```

The problem is the missing space between `join` and `$dir`. It's possible that `$dir` will have been replaced with a literal path and it might be inside a `list load` or any number of other options, but the bug is the missing space. That missing space is causing the path to be added to the subcommand name (`join`) and the `file` command rightly complains about that in that characteristic way.

The `pkgIndex.tcl` file is probably pretty short. It shouldn't take you long to spot where the problem is now that you know what you're looking for.

---

The *deeper cause* of this is less clear. It might be a problem with path replacement during installation, or with sloppy testing on behalf of Spirent (though I wouldn't expect that; even the most cursory of tests should spot this problem), or any number of other things.